# How to correctly include the support library in non-Eclipse Android application

Tags: android, linux, ant, android-support-library

I am thinking how to get Android' s support library to include and compile outside Eclipse. I am using Linux as my build environment and I am not using any IDE for creating apps, only the basic Android SDK. I have only come over answers to this question regarding Eclipse, but how can I do it using only Ant and Android SDK?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you are not using `GridLayout`:

Step #1: Copy `android-support-v4.jar` or `android-support-v13.jar` from your SDK into the `libs/` directory of your project.

Step #2: There is no step #2.

Choose `android-support-v13.jar` if you are using native fragments (versus the Android Support package's own backport) and you want to use them with things like `ViewPager` that are part of the Android Support package.

`GridLayout` makes things a bit more complicated, in that it is an Android library project. You would need to follow [the instructions for how to use an Android library project in a command-line project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject), probably working off of a copy of the official project.

All of this stuff can be found in the `extras/` directory of wherever your SDK is installed.

Comment: Note: for some extras, e.g. `google-play-services`, just the jar may not be enough because of missing resources. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35395369/895245 for a method

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this automation article http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html

Make sure to generate a valid build.xml file for ant/android building `android update project --path /path/to/project`

then just `ant clean debug`

You can also checkout the official doc http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html