# unable to remove the error to do with com.google.android.gms import

Tags: java, android

An eeror pops everytime i try importing  com.google.android.gms in my java class in android. my application has oogle maps and cant run without these imports. All help highly appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is com.google.android.gms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309694/where-is-com-google-android-gms)

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to update/install google maps using SDK Manager...