# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpt$zza

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, classnotfoundexception, google-api-client

I'm developing an Android app that involves authenticating the user using the GoogleApiClientBuilder class. The error occurs during runtime when I hit this part of my code:

```
GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN);
```

This works perfectly fine on Android 5.0.1 but when I try it on API level 19 (Kitkat), I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpt$zza
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.tubealert.tubealert.Splash.buildGoogleApiClient(Splash.java:58)
        at com.tubealert.tubealert.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

After doingh some research I found it may have been Proguard stripping away the necessary classes but whether I enable or disable minifyEnabled, it doesn't work:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Then I did some more research and figured maybe it as a multiDex issue but I enabled it and I'm even compiling it as one of my dependencies

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.tubealert.tubealert"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled = true
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    configurations { all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava' }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev134-1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1'
}
```

So as of no it only works on Lollipop but nothing lower than that.. Please help me if you can!

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309694/where-is-com-google-android-gms

Comment: hey thanks for commenting, the thing is my package isn't gone, it just can't find certain classes on any api level less than lollipop

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Figured it out. Just had to follow every single step in setting up google play services! Silly mistake on my end.

Comment: Can you explain what you did? I have tried the one you used, but it is not working in android 4.4.2!

Comment: This is not an answer. Please explain what you did to overcome this problem.

Comment: This answer is not useful al all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add obfuscation rules for the Google API's : 
[ProGuard Configuration](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/calendar-android-sample/proguard-google-api-client.txt)